# JTextField unable to use input in if statement java

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield, gettext

I am currently working on and assignment that requires me to create a custom missing fields exception. I have to take in the data from a GUI and make sure that all the fields received input. The problem I am having is that whenever I take the input and put it into a string using .getText() i am unable to use it in any kind of if statement. What i mean by this is that if i write an if statement using exactly what i know is going to be in the JTextField it does not work. I am somewhat new to java so i could just be missing something very easy.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class PersonFrame extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
static LinkedList<Person> listOfObjects = new LinkedList<Person>(); 
JTextField fName;
JTextField lName;
JTextField Height;


public PersonFrame()
{
    setTitle("Person");
    setSize(200, 130);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2));
    add(new JLabel("First Name"));
    fName = new JTextField();
    add(fName);
    add(new JLabel("Last Name"));
    lName = new JTextField();
    add(lName);
    add(new JLabel("Height"));
    Height = new JTextField();
    add(Height);
    JButton jbtSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    JButton jbtCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    add(jbtSubmit);
    add(jbtCancel);
    SubmitListenerClass listener1 = new SubmitListenerClass();
    CancelListenerClass listener2 = new CancelListenerClass();
    jbtSubmit.addActionListener(listener1);
    jbtCancel.addActionListener(listener2);
    setVisible(true);

}

public void CloseWindow()
{
    this.setVisible(false);
}
public Person SubmitData()
{
    String fn = fName.getText();
    String ln = lName.getText();
    int h = Integer.parseInt(Height.getText());

    Person p = new Person(fn, ln, h);
    int i = OneMissingFieldException(p);
    int j = MultipleMissingFieldException(p);
    if(i == 1 && j == 1)
    System.out.println(p);
    return p;
    }


public void OutputList() throws IOException
{
    if(listOfObjects.peekFirst()!=null)
    {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter("outputp.txt") );
        Object[] pa = listOfObjects.toArray();
        pw.println("Person");
        for(int x = 0; x<pa.length; x++)
        {
            pw.println(pa[x]);
            pw.println("");
        }
        pw.close();
    }
 }

class CancelListenerClass implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    CloseWindow();
  }
}
class SubmitListenerClass implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


      listOfObjects.add(SubmitData());
    CloseWindow();

  }
  public int OneMissingFieldException(Person p) 
 {

    String fName = ((Person) p).getFName();


    try 
    {
    if(fName == "" || fName == null || fName == " ")

        throw new MissingFieldException();

    }
    catch(MissingFieldException mfe){
        System.out.println("You did not enter a first name." + mfe);
        return 0;
    }


String lName = ((Person) p).getFName(); 
try 
    {
    if(lName == "" || lName == null || lName == " ")

        throw new MissingFieldException();          
    }
    catch(MissingFieldException mfe){
        System.out.println("You did not enter a last name." + mfe);
        return 0;
    }
int height = ((Person) p).getHeight();  
try 
    {

    if(!(height >= 0) )

        throw new MissingFieldException();
    }
    catch(MissingFieldException mfe){
        System.out.println("You did not enter a height." + mfe);
    return 0;
    }

return 1;

 }


public int MultipleMissingFieldException(Person p) 
{
if (p instanceof Person)
{
    String fName = ((Person) p).getFName();
    String lName = ((Person) p).getFName();
    try 
    {
    if((fName == "" || fName == null || fName == " ")&&(lName == "" || lName == null || lName == " "))

        throw new MissingFieldException();

    }
    catch(MissingFieldException mfe){
        System.out.println("You did not enter a first name or last name." + mfe);
        return 0;
    }

    }
String fName = ((Person) p).getFName();
int height = ((Person) p).getHeight();
try 
{
if((fName == "" || fName == null || fName == " ")&&(!(height >=0)))

    throw new MissingFieldException();

}
catch(MissingFieldException mfe){
    System.out.println("You did not enter a first name or height." + mfe);
    return 0;
}

String lName = ((Person) p).getFName();

    try 
    {
    if((lName == "" || lName == null || lName == " ")&&(!(height >=0)))

        throw new MissingFieldException();          
    }
    catch(MissingFieldException mfe){
        System.out.println("You did not enter a last name and height." +        mfe);
        return 0;
    }


 return 1;
}



}
```

Comment: On which line are you facing problem ?

Comment: It is very hard to find your exact problem because the code snippet you provided is incomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making a fairly easy mistake, I've made it plenty of times.
Because "String" variables are NOT data types (such as int, long, and double) but are in fact Objects of the String class (denoted by the uppercase first letter) you have to check whether the value in your string class is equal to the value that you want to check by using the .equals("String value to be checked") function on the end of the string you want to check.
So an example would be, I want to figure out if myString is equal to (has the same word/value) as yourString. I would write:

```
myString.equals(yourString); //which would return a boolean
```

as opposed to how you have written it as

```
myString == yourString; //which does not work
```

Answer (score 2):

With String you have to use `string.equals(otherString)`, not `string == otherString`.